# Can a NHibernate transaction be continued after an exception?

Tags: nhibernate

I am using NHibernate to save objects that require that one of the properties on these objects must be unique. The design of the system is such that it is possible that an attempt may be made occasionally to save the same object twice. This of course causes a violation of the uniqueness constraint and NHibernate throws an exception. The exception happens at the time I am attempting to save the object, rather than at Transaction.Commit() time. When this happens I want to simply catch the exception, discard the object and continue on saving other similar objects. However, I have not found a way to allow this to happen. Once that exception has happened I cannot carry on to save other objects and commit the transaction.

The only work-around I have found for this is to always check if the object exists first by running a query on the unique property. That works, but it seems unnecessarily expensive. I would like to avoid that extra hit to the db. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue, you've described, must be solved on a higher level then NHibernate session. Take a look at [9.8. Exception handling](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-exceptions), extract:

> If the ISession throws an exception you should immediately rollback
>   the transaction, call ISession.Close() and discard the ISession
>   instance. Certain methods of ISession will not leave the session in a
>   consistent state.

So, what I would suggest, wrap the call to your Data layer (DL) with some validation. Place the if/try logic outside of the Session.

Because even in case, that we are using versioning (see [5.1.7. version](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-version)) *(a very powerful way how to survive concurrency)* ... we are provided with `StaleExceptions` and have to solve them outside of the DL

Comment: Doing a check outside the NHibernate session doesn't make sense to me. By doing the check for an existing object within the current transaction I think that gives me a better guarantee of not hitting a collision. In other words, I think my current work-around seems like the best approach. Another approach might be to discard the current transaction upon a collision and open another one. Either way, the documentation seems clear that once an exception like this has happened the current transaction must be rolled back and the session discarded.

Comment: I am afraid, that your decision is wrong. Unless you will use Transaction isolation level ala "Serializable"... this approach is unsafe. Because, there could be many concurrent (well you just said that this is your case) users/client_apps trying to: Inside of your "session" 1) load from DB to C# current data, to know if there is no conflict..2) then save. There is so much time during that period, that it could be changed already by another thread. While, doing this a level up/BL -the user/Client can decided what to do next...how to solve the "same value already exist". This is a clear design;)